# awk prints wrong variable out to file

Tags: shell, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Objective

I am trying to break up the date shown in field 2 to a variable "year and "month" which are then printed back into my file as 2 new fields at the end. I have a for loop as there are many files I'm doing this to, which will be cat'd at the end.

### Issue

AWK prints field 3 for one of the variables and a blank for the other at the end of the file.

### file - test.tsv

```
client  2020-03-15  platform    3096431 2686357 0.868   2544716 0.8220000000000001  2509205 0.8100000000000001  2046915 0.6609999999999999  0.189   0.053   0.0526  0   0.0001  0   0.013   0.009599999999999999    0   0.0031  0   0   0.0005999999999999999   0.37    0.0757  0   0.0365  0.2326  0.025   1238347 0.494   0.494   1270858 0.507   0   0   1   0.302   33  202.5   1270864 0.507   157387  0.063   357414  0.142   723540  0.288
```

### Code

```
 ##note the tabs in the cut command are correct in my code but might end up as spaces in the post
    for f4 in $(find *.tsv);do
            name=$(echo $f4 | sed -Ee 's/-filename.tsv//')
            month=$(cat $f4 | cut -d "      " -f 2 | awk -F"-" -v OFS='-' '{print $2}')
            year=$(cat $f4 | cut -d "       " -f 2 | awk -F"-" -v OFS='-' '{print $1}')
            awk -v month="$month" -v year="$year" -F"\t" -v OFS='\t' '{print $0,  $month,   $year}' $f4 > $name-dates.tsv
            mv $f4 tsv
    done
```

### Current Output

```
client  2020-03-15  platform    3096431 2686357 0.868   2544716 0.8220000000000001  2509205 0.8100000000000001  2046915 0.6609999999999999  0.189   0.053   0.0526  0   0.0001  0   0.013   0.009599999999999999    0   0.0031  0   0   0.0005999999999999999   0.37    0.0757  0   0.0365  0.2326  0.025   1238347 0.494   0.494   1270858 0.507   0   0   1   0.302   33  202.5   1270864 0.507   157387  0.063   357414  0.142   723540  0.288   platform
```

### Desired Output

```
client  2020-03-15  platform    3096431 2686357 0.868   2544716 0.8220000000000001  2509205 0.8100000000000001  2046915 0.6609999999999999  0.189   0.053   0.0526  0   0.0001  0   0.013   0.009599999999999999    0   0.0031  0   0   0.0005999999999999999   0.37    0.0757  0   0.0365  0.2326  0.025   1238347 0.494   0.494   1270858 0.507   0   0   1   0.302   33  202.5   1270864 0.507   157387  0.063   357414  0.142   723540  0.288   03  2020
```

### What I've tried

Many googles and a lot of reworks for the script but I don't seem to be able to get it right. Based on my variables "month" and "year" I am capturing the correct input but something in the awk command doesn't pass it correctly. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `-d "       "`  - use `-d $'\t'`. The current output you presented suggest there is no tab between `client` and `2020-03-15`, please check.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the suggestion on how to do a tab in another way. But is that going to cause an issue with the later awk command?

Comment: `cut` default delim is a tab so just drop it. Actually drop it all and use @EdMorton's full awk solution below. :D

Comment: `$'\t` and `"<tab character here>"` means the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it in one call to awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {split($2,d,/-/); print $0, d[2], d[1]}' test.tsv
client  2020-03-15      platform        3096431 2686357 0.868   2544716 0.8220000000000001  2509205 0.8100000000000001      2046915 0.6609999999999999      0.189   0.053       0.0526  0       0.0001  0       0.013   0.009599999999999999    0       0.0031      0       0       0.0005999999999999999   0.37    0.0757  0       0.0365  0.2326      0.025   1238347 0.494   0.494   1270858 0.507   0       0       1       0.302       33      202.5   1270864 0.507   157387  0.063   357414  0.142   723540  0.288       03      2020
```

See also [why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice), https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html for some (but not all) of the other other issues in your script. I highly recommend you run all scripts you write through `shellcheck` (e.g. https://www.shellcheck.net/) until you understand the basics.